# Need custom picture field for pages

Tags: images, customization

I want to have a picture or multiple pictures on each page in wordpress.

AFAIK there are two standart ways of doing this

1. in WYSIWYG editor, attach file etc
2. widgets.

Problem is, those wont do for my clients.

So how can I make a custom field on each page, where the user selects a pic if he wants.

I know there is a plugin, "sidebar per page" but i would like to do it without plugin, and if possible all the page editing happens on admin>pages>page x without the need to go to widgets are and so on.

Pls share if there is a way to do this, or what it would take.

TY

Comment: Would featured images work for you?

Comment: thx for the tip. ill check that now. do you add each pages image on the page edit interface? it seems this isnt a plugin, which is good.

Comment: You would add the image via the edit form, and it is WordPress core functionality (but might need to be enabled for you post type).

Comment: as im reading now this is functionallyty specific to posts. but can it also be applied to pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like "Featured" or "Thumbnail" images would work. These are enabled by default for 'posts'. For 'pages' they need to be enabled, but that is as simple as adding [`add_post_type_support( 'page', 'thumbnail' );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support) to your theme's `functions.php` hooked on `init`, and, of course, modifying the theme template files to display the featured image.

```
function add_featured_to_post_wpse_83508() {
  add_post_type_support( 'page', 'thumbnail' );
}
add_action('init','add_featured_to_post_wpse_83508');
```

The theme itself has to register its support with [`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

In the Loop, [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) will display the image

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent (very popular, very mature, very well documented) plugin called 'Advanced custom fields' that makes working with custom fields really easy. It's what I have used.

Featured image is good but I'm not sure it allows multiple images.